# <nobr> Tag Support

Tags: bug, markdown, google-chrome

I thought that we supported HTML tags in questions.

I'm using the latest version of Chrome and the `<nobr>` tag works fine for me on any HTML page, but *not* in any Stack Overflow posts: [Prevent Long String From Wrapping on Symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28454791/prevent-long-string-from-wrapping-on-symbols)

It appears that Markdown does not support the `<nobr>` tag: *[What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites/135909#135909)*

Is there another way to prevent a non-code section of a question from breaking apart words that contain symbols?

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see `<nobr>` on this list at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909

Comment: Stack Exchange only supports a *subset* of HTML. Not all HTML.

Comment: The <pre> tag is available, if you don't mind it being rendered in a fixed-width font.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Interesting that behaves just like \`\`. That's not precisely what I was looking for, but it seems as close as we can get. Could you put that in an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [list of available HTML tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites/135909#135909), the <pre> tag is available, if you don't mind it being rendered in a fixed-width font.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the characters on which the line breaks happen, you may find an alternative "non‑breaking" Unicode variant.

I had the problem with a hyphen, and could replace it with "‑": U+2011 "NON-BREAKING HYPHEN" (UTF-8: 0xE2 0x80 0x91).

For spaces, you can of course use the non-breaking space U+00A0 `&nbsp;`